# Eigenvalues of a circulant: DFT or Inverse DFT Convention?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-analysis, fourier-transform, numerical-linear-algebra

Currently, most engineering texts (and webpages including Wikipedia) define forward discrete Fourier transform with a negative sign on the exponential. This is a convention and the inverse discrete Fourier transform has a positive sign. It is not uncommon to see the opposite convention in older literature. However, I am interested in the diagonalization of a circulant matrix and the labeling of its eigenvalues is little bit confusing even in modern texts. I am searching Google Books. I thought the negative sign convention on the exponent in DFT is currently practiced but many latest books appear to be inconsistent in labeling eigenvalues of a circulant. What is the accepted practice among mathematicians (I am coming from chemistry background)?

If we diagonalize a circulant matrix, some books say, the eigenvalues of a circulant correspond to the *inverse* Fourier transform of the row of the circulant matrix. Whereas, many other lecture notes on the circulant from top universties and other books say that the eigenvalues of a circulant correspond to the *discrete Fourier transform*.

One example, one book "*An Introduction to Computational Stochastic PDEs*" says,

> **Lemma 6.44** Let $W$ be the $N \times N$ Fourier matrix (see Definition
> 1.95) with entries $w_{i j}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \omega^{(i-1)(j-1)}$ for $\omega:=\mathrm{e}^{-2 \pi \mathrm{i} / N}$. For $\boldsymbol{c}
> > \in \mathbb{R}^N, W \boldsymbol{c}$ and $W^* \boldsymbol{c}$ are
> Hermitian. For a Hermitian vector $\boldsymbol{c} \in \mathbb{C}^N, W
> > \boldsymbol{c}$ and $W^* \boldsymbol{c}$ are real.
>
> The eigenvalues of a circulant matrix are given by $N$ times the
> inverse DFT of the first column and the eigenvectors are the columns
> of the Fourier matrix $W$. This leads to the following factorisation
> of a circulant matrix.

Another one states

> 3.2 Matrix Operations on Circulant Matrices The following theorem summarizes the properties derived in the previous section regarding
> eigenvalues and eigenvectors of circulant matrices and provides some
> easy implications.
>
> Theorem 3.1. Every circulant matrix $C$ has eigenvectors $y^{(m)}=$
> $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1, e^{-2 \pi i m / n}, \cdots, e^{-2 \pi
> > i(n-1) / n}\right)^{\prime}, m=0,1, \ldots, n-1$, and corresponding
> eigenvalues $$ \psi_m=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k e^{-2 \pi i m k / n} $$ and
> can be expressed in the form $C=U \Psi U^*$, where $U$ has the
> eigenvectors as columns in order and $\Psi$ is
> $\operatorname{diag}\left(\psi_k\right)$. In particular all circulant
> matrices share the same eigenvectors, the same matrix $U$ works for
> all circulant matrices, and any matrix of the form $C=U \Psi U^*$ is
> circulant.

This book implies that eigenvalues of a circulant are discrete Fourier transform not the inverse DFT.

Another one: This one clearly says so.

> Example B.4 The real matrices $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$
> below are Toeplitz and circulant, respectively. $$
>  \boldsymbol{A}=\left[\begin{array}{lll} 2 & 5 & 1 \\ 4 & 2 & 5 \\ 3 &
>  4 & 2 \end{array}\right] \quad \boldsymbol{B}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
>  2 & 5 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 5 \\ 5 & 1 & 2 \end{array}\right] $$ If
> $\boldsymbol{A}$ is an $N \times N$ circulant matrix, then the
> following holds:
>
> - The eigenvectors of $\boldsymbol{A}$ equal the columns of the Fourier matrix $\boldsymbol{U}$ in (B.7).
> - The eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A}$ equal the entries of $\boldsymbol{U}^* \boldsymbol{a}$ where $\boldsymbol{a}$ is any column
>   of $\boldsymbol{A}$. Hence, the eigenvalues of a circulant matrix are
>   directly the DFT of any of the columns (or rows) of that matrix [139].

Reference 139 is a a review paper on Toeplitz and Circulants.

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** Are the eigenvalues of a circulant matrix given by the DFT or Inverse DFT of a column of matrix elements?

**A:** It makes no difference, the list $f$ of Fourier coefficients and the list $f'$ of inverse Fourier coefficients of a list of $N$ complex numbers are identical up to a permutation. (This is true simply because $e^{2\pi i kn/N}=e^{-2\pi i k'n/N}$ with $k'=N-k$.)

Comment: Thanks,  could you clarify the term "identical up to a permutation"?

Comment: Basically, if we have a sequence of real numbers (=signal), whether we take a discrete Fourier transform of that sequence with a plus sign or a minus sign on the exponential, the output will be complex conjugate of each other.

Comment: the statement that $f$ and $f'$ are identical up to a permutation (meaning, a reordering of the elements in the list) also holds if the circulant has _complex_ matrix elements